# import css from node_modules in meteor 1.4 with react

Tags: css, reactjs, meteor, npm, node-modules

I want to use an npm package, namely `react-date-picker` in my Meteor 1.4 project using React. The `react-date-picker` package comes with some css that must be included in order to render correctly. I need to tell meteor to load `node_modules/react-date-picker/index.css` and include it with the rest of its css, but I'm at a loss on how to do this. Others have suggested that you can simply import the css from within the .jsx component like this

`import 'react-date-picker/index.css'`

but doing so results in a crashing server that chokes on the first line of the css (as it appears to be parsed as a standard javascript file)

```
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { .react-date-field {
                                                              ^
) SyntaxError: Unexpected token .
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:373:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
    at Module.Mp.load (/Users/gsferrer/.meteor/packages/babel-compiler/.6.9.1.7f3rvr++os+web.browser+web.cordova/npm/node_modules/reify/node/runtime.js:16:23)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
    at npmRequire (/Users/gsferrer/Projects/xxx/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/npm-require.js:129:10)
    at Module.Mp.useNode (packages/modules-runtime/modules-runtime.js:69:1)
=> Exited with code: 1
=> Your application is crashing. Waiting for file change.
```

So what is the preferred method to import css from node_modules using Meteor with React?

Answer (score 1):

As you say, it appears to be parsed as JS. However, importing a CSS this way is correct and usually works, so there must be something weird going on... So I'm going to try a wild guess: Try renaming the file from `index.css` to something else, like `react-date-picker.css`. It could be that the "index" name is triggering the JS interpretation.

Comment: nope, it still complains, regardless of the name of the css. I switched to the `react-datetime` package whose css file is `react-datetime.css` but the same error occurs.

Answer (score 0):

I have been stuck for days on this issue too (I am new to the node.js/Meteor/React/JavaScript world). I needed to import a CSS file in **node_modules/react-datagrid/index.css**

My working solution (applied to a tiny application that should make it easy to understand; I only display a datagrid using hard-coded data) is available on my [GitHub repository](https://github.com/kevinrue/reactJS/tree/master/reactDataGrid) (commit 902c92c). The application is called "reactDataGrid", it is a subfolder of the repository, you just need to run "meteor" within that folder.

The key steps in my case were:

- `npm install webpack --save-dev` to install web pack for the project
- to create a **.babelrc** file with the content described [here](http://survivejs.com/webpack/advanced-techniques/configuring-react/) (and copied below). I believe this helps webpack parse the JSX syntax of react.

**.babelrc**

```
{
  "presets": [
    [
      "es2015",
      {
        "modules": false
      }
    ],
    "react"
  ]
}
```

- add `require('react-datagrid/index.css')` statement inside my **client/main.jsx** file, that tells webpack to include that CSS file in the dependency tree of my app. This is actually an instruction described in the README of the zippyui/react-datagrid GitHub repository. (Unfortunately stackoverflow limits to two links in my post, so I cannot link it here anymore)

I cannot guarantee that this is the *preferred* method of doing it, but I can say that it works for me. I hope it helps.

Best,
Kevin